# How can I include a file from a higher parent directory?

Tags: php

How can I include a file from a higher parent directory in my `index.php` file?

**Code:**

```
//This is my index page
include_once "./../../../idea/file.html";
```

**The project structure**

[image]

Comment: `Depth 4` and 3x `..` doesn't quite match up

Comment: `include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../idea/file.html';` ??

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` should be `__DIR__` instead.

Comment: `__DIR__` Will return my current directory, so i can navigate now from this path based on depth, right?

Comment: Just in case (or for general info) `__DIR__` is available from PHP 5.3, so `dirname(__FILE__)` is probably habit.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a dot. You will need to use one `../` for each depth you want to got up.

Try:

```
include_once "../../../../idea/file.html";
```

Comment: ,That is not my interest, I want to know the best way.

Comment: @FrayneKonok You should indicate that in your question, since there are many ways to include files and the example you posted in your question is non-working, so implies a "fix" is required.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your base path is responsive directory. You can include any file like this:

```
include_once(BASE_PATH."idea/file.html");
```

Comment: from where the `BASE_PATH` come from?

Comment: @FrayneKonok You'd have to manually set it! (Which isn't such a helpful example... how do you set it?)